# Unable to connect to Hive from pyspark with anonymous user error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have done my research on how to connect spark from hive but still not able to figure it out -

Here is the sample code -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("My Spark Application") \
  .config("spark.hadoop.hive.server2.jdbc.url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default?**user=hive**") \
  .enableHiveSupport() \
  .getOrCreate()

from pyspark_llap.sql.session import HiveWarehouseSession
hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()  

hive.execute("show tables")
```

Error is -

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAccessControlException: Permission denied: user [anonymous] does not have [USE] privile
ge on [default]
```

Doesn't matter what I try I can't get rid of the user anonymous. From the doc it has been suggested to pass the username in hive URL the way I passed in the above code but still the user anonymous is showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some [Cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/integrating-hive/content/hive_configure_a_spark_hive_connection.html):

> The Hive connection string must include a user name and password; otherwise, Spark and Hive cannot connect. For example:
>
> `jdbc:hive2://<host>:2181;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2-interactive;user=<user name>;password=<password>`

Seems like you might not be using the correct delimiter in your connection string. Try using `;` instead of `?`. So in your case, it would be: `"jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;user=hive"`

Comment: Thanks , I have resolved the issue by passing the password as well. When I changed the delimeter it gave the same error but after passing the password it worked , thanks for your help